# How would I use conditional types in this scenario?

Tags: typescript, discord.js

i have an interface `ICommand` in ICommand.ts and an object `CommandConditions` in another file

```js
//// in CommandConditions.ts
import { GuildMember, Message, VoiceChannel } from 'discord.js'

const CommandConditions = {
  isMember(
    message: Message,
    replies: {
      noMember?: string
      noVoiceChannel?: string
      voiceChannelNotSame?: string
    } = {}
  ): message is Message & { member: GuildMember } {
    // setting default values for reply properties.
    if (!replies.noMember) replies.noMember = 'Member is unavailable.'
    // message.member by default is GuildMember | null
    if (!message.member) {
      message.reply(replies.noMember)
      return false
    }
    return true
  },
  isInVoiceChannel(
    message: Message,
    replies: {
      noMember?: string
      noVoiceChannel?: string
    } = {}
  ): message is Message & {
    member: GuildMember & {
      voice: { channel: VoiceChannel }
    }
  } {
    // setting default values for reply properties.
    if (!replies.noMember) replies.noMember = 'Member is unavailable.'
    if (!replies.noVoiceChannel)
      replies.noVoiceChannel = 'You are not in a voice channel.'
    // message.member by default is GuildMember | null
    if (!message.member) {
      message.reply(replies.noMember)
      return false
    }
    // message.member.voice.channel by default is VoiceChannel | null
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.reply(replies.noVoiceChannel)
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

````js
//// in ICommand.ts
import { CommandConditions } from './CommandConditions.ts'

type CommandConditionsKey = keyof typeof CommandConditions

export interface ICommand {
  conditions?: {
    [key in CommandConditionsKey]?: Parameters<typeof CommandConditions[CommandConditionsKey]>[1] // so I can for example do { isMember: { noMember: 'custom reply when member is unvailable' } }
  }
  run(message: Message): void
}
``` and a command running file that checks if `command.conditions` exist or not if it exists check if every condition specified returns true if not then return if yes then call the run function `command.run(message)` and another file that calls the RunCommand function and passes the message argument```ts
////in RunCommand.ts
export const RunCommand = (message: Message, command: ICommand) => {
  const satisfiesEveryConditionIfAny = () => {
        if (!command.conditions) return false
        return Object.entries(command.conditions).every(condition =>
          CommandConditions[condition[0] as CommandConditionsKey](message, { ...condition[1] }
          )
        )
      }

  if (!satisfiesEveryConditionIfAny()) return

  command.run(message)
}
````

now what i want to do is when im making a command i.e. an object with interface ICommand i want the type of message argument of the run function change accordingly to the conditions property, and not do any checks if no `conditions` property is given, and make the `message` type `never` if conflicting conditions are provided?

```js
////example (the methods use in the examples are made up to make the code simpler)

// a command that plays music and other similar commands that require the user to be in a voice channel
const playCommand: ICommand = {
  conditions: { isInVoiceChannel: { noVoiceChannel: 'Join a voice channel dummy.' } },
//since the RunCommand file will only run the command if CommandCondition.isInVoiceChannel return true and message should be of type `Message & { member: GuildMember & { voice: { channel: VoiceChannel } } }
  run(message) { message.member.voice.channel.join() }
}

// a command that gets the members info
const infoCommand: ICommand = {
  conditions: { isMember: {} },
//message should be of type `Message & { member: GuildMember }
  run(message) { message.member.getInfo() }
}

// a command with no conditions
const noConditionsCommand: ICommand = {
//message should be of type `Message
  run(message) { message.delete() }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NdjqkW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz oke thx, i did

Comment: Thanks. I don't know anything about discord.js so I don't know if I can help much.  If you try to reduce the code here to a *minimal* example of the sort of problem you're having without being tied up with discord.js, more people will be able to help you. Right now my approach would look like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mMx3rN) where you make `ICommand` generic in the particular condition keys you are using. If that works for you I could write up an answer; if not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz i was thinking, what if i dont give any `conditions` property it will still try to do the checks? and how do i make the `message`  type `never` if i have conflicting conditions

Comment: Are these followup questions or requirements for the existing question? If they are requirements then you should [edit] the post to specify exactly what you're talking about (I don't really understand what you mean without a [mre] showing the issue, and the sentence "change accordingly to the conditions property" in the question is not specific enough for me to understand).

Comment: On the other hand, if they are followup questions then they should probably get their own posts and we should keep this question as-is.  In this case, can you tell me whether [my prior suggested approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMx3rN) does or does not meet the needs as stated in the question?

Comment: @jcalz its for the existing question, yes, i updated the question